# How can I call java rest service from java stored procedure?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

How can I call java restful service from java stored procedure? I need help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate you procedure into small procedures and call rest service from Java.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not able to find the logic for call to rest service from java stored procedure.

Comment: i imagine that you want to call your web service in the middle of your procedure, then you can create two SP, CALL the first PS from JAVA, Call WS From Java, the result returned by WS will be the input of the second procedure CALLED from JAVA. Or You can stock the result in a table and the call the table from the second SP. Hope this helps